# org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

When trying to run my application i am getting an error like this

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.bootstrapServiceContext(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:120)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:84)
    at org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(BootstrapApplicationListener.java:1)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:127)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:345)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
```

How solve this and run my application.

Comment: <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>

<spring-cloud-netflix-core.version>1.1.7.RELEASE</spring-cloud-netflix-core.version>

<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-netflix-core.version}</version>
            </dependency>

Comment: You may want to check [ask]

Answer (score 2):

The version of Spring Boot that you are using is incompatible with the version of Spring Cloud that you are using. They are also both rather old and no longer supported. If you must use Spring Cloud Netflix 1.1.7.RELEASE then you should use Spring Boot 1.3.x with it.

Comment: i need to have springboot version 2.2.6 , so which version of spring cloud should i use. I tried a few by still facing issue. If you could help me it would be great .@andy

Comment: Try `2.2.2.RELEASE`

Comment: I tried 2.2.2.RELEASE ,but Unfortunately i am getting feign error , getting like this "package org.springframework.cloud does not exist" , and feign library import failed 
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.EnableFeignClients;

Answer (score -1):

Need to use import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;
and include this

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).